# How to add Crop Library Github

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I want to add SimpleCropView to my Android Project from Github https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView but dont know how to proceed.My Project Gradle file are as follows.

Project Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Module Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "loginscreen.example.com.girviapp"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jcifs-1.3.18.jar')

}
```

Comment: The documentation seems to explain quite nicely how to [add the library as a dependency](https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView#download) and how to [use the widget](https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView#basic-usage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following dependency in your `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'
}
```

Comment: Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8

Comment: Should i have to add module or library from Android Studio UI

Comment: i just added the dependency and it successfully compiled.where are you adding this dependency.

Comment: Sorry to ask but i am new to Android Deepakji,I added it in Module[Gradle].Before adding the above line what else we have to do

Comment: after writing this line `compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'` inside the dependencies in the Module[Gradle], just sync your project.

Comment: Sir, now error:Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.

Comment: Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found. this is the errpr you getting

Comment: Yes this is the Error(21,0)

Comment: have you downloaded the library from github and referencing in your app.

Comment: Yes I downloaded it, Imported Module from Android Studio .Added dependency to my app from Android UI "Project Structure"

Comment: you don't have to do it. Just remove the dependency from project structure.

Comment: Just create a new android studio project and add `compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'` inside this Module Gradle Dependency and sync. Nothing else to do.

Comment: Done as u said still having the same error in new project as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90366/discussion-between-deepak-goyal-and-lalit-jadiya).